# load data to hive from HDFS

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I would move my data from a old cluster to a new one, and these are the steps I took:

Step 1:

I moved data from the HDFS 1 (old one) to HDFS 2 (new one) by distcp:

```
hadoop distcp hdfs://nn1:8020/apps/hive/warehouse/d_data09.db/mytab hdfs://nn2:8020/apps/hive/warehouse/d_data09.db/mytab
```

Step 2:

Now I have my data on the new cluster, and I have to put it on HIVE, so:

at first time, I've connected to beeline and I've created a database:

```
beeline -u "jdbc:hive2://nn01:2181,nn03:2181/;serviceDiscoveryMode=zooKeeper;zooKeeperNamespace=hiveserver2"

Create database d_data09;
```

Step 3:

```
create external table mytab (
col2 string, 
col1 string, 
col3 string, 
col4 string, 
col5 string, 
col6 string
)
row format delimited fields terminated by ','
location 'apps/hive/warehouse/d_data09.db/mytab';
```

this is the structer of the table:

```
2017-07-01 00:01:43 |1  |not   |yes   |101   |555   |-
```

The result:

I can say that the table `Mytab` is created with success and i can see that the `totalSize` is 26Go which mean that the data is EXTERNATED (I've not load data but I just used External data) with success.

when I type : `Describe formatted elements` I can notice that the description is littlely the same. but when I made a query to select data, I notice that all the colones are agregated at the first colone:

```
 2017-07-01 00:01:43 1notyes101555- | NULL  | NULL   | NULL    | NULL   | NULL   | NULL
```

What did I make wrong?

Comment: could  you include the first few lines of your file? `hdfs dfs -cat apps/hive/warehouse/d_data09.db/mytab | head`

Comment: You've said `row format delimited fields terminated by ','` but your data appears to be delimited by a different field

Comment: @bpgergo mytab is a directory with million of files

Comment: it seems that is the issue but I don't know what is the form of this files in the .../mytab

Comment: I bet you that the file has non printable characters separating the fields

Comment: @cricket_007 how can I make sure that there is non printable characters

Comment: I would do `hdfs dfs -cat apps/hive/warehouse/d_data09.db/mytab | head | hexdump` in the first namenode... Alternatively, I would not have used distcp... Export the table, then copy that, and import it https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+ImportExport

Comment: @cricket_007 if that's true so you ..!! I don't know...

Comment: Also... You clearly show 6 fields. Why are you only using `col2 int, col1 string`?

Comment: that's just a example to explain my issue because I can't use data directly here

Comment: @cricket_007 check out update

Comment: @cricket_007 Export/import of 2To of data takes about 3 months to do it

Comment: @cricket_007 You have to use distcp to move data between cluster, this is the fastest way to do that

Comment: 2To? You mean 2TB? You only say 26GB in the question. You're other option is to backup and import only the hive metastore. Distcp the tables into exactly the same locations on the other HDFS

Comment: **Export** Hive table. **Distcp** that metadata and table data. **Import** the table so you don't need to do `create table`

Comment: @cricket_007 in my question I said 26Go (this is the first table I have), I still have 100 tables to move, so I don't think the import/export will be a good solution

Comment: Yes it will be. It's far better than manually running all create table statements yourself.

Comment: do you realize that create manully a 26GB table takes about 5min however import  takes entire day, so import+ export= 2 days (2 days is the time to finish the creation of the database). additional I can automate the creation with script `beeline -u ... -f script`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the field delimiter you specify in your Hive create table command is correct. You specified ','

```
row format delimited fields terminated by ','
```

Check you actual field delimiter by checking the first few lines of your data file

```
hdfs dfs -cat apps/hive/warehouse/d_data09.db/mytab | head
```

Comment: there is no delimiter even a normale space, the fields are overlapped